# Question was closed for "seeking debugging help" even though that's CLEARLY not the case

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459177/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-in-bash-terminal) a while ago about the fact that after I ran a specific C++ program to compute Fibonacci series elements, **it worked perfectly fine**, however after I tried to open a new terminal tab it gave me an error. It *clearly* has **nothing** to do with debugging help, however it was closed for that reason. Also, there is a clear problem statement as shown. I emphasized the fact that it did what it was supposed before it was closed, and yet it got closed. What just happened?

Comment: Your program doesn't work under certain circumstances. Finding out why it doesn't work is what *debugging* is all about.

Comment: Of course this is asking for debugging help, what else do you think it does if not so?

Comment: **de·bug**
*dēˈbəɡ/*

..1.identify and remove errors from (computer hardware or software).

Comment: @Martijn It's not the program I need help with, it's that my terminal broke!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not seeking debugging help because the program isn't the problem, it's that my terminal broke when I ran the file, which doesn't do anything when I try it on another computer.

Comment: @000: and you are 100% certain that the two events are related then?

Comment: @000 So if _breaking your terminal_ is unrelated to your program, why are you posting it there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because it was working fine before running the program and after I ran the program it broke.

Comment: @000: your post certainly looks like a debugging issue though; if your program is really to blame, then that's a bug in your program. That'd still require debugging.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not exactly sure, but 90% I bet.

Comment: @000: correlation is *not* causation. Just because two events are closely linked in time doesn't mean that one caused the other. Your terminal breaking can be a coincidence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's definitely not a bug in the program as it works fine on another computer or in Xcode.

Comment: Also, I know correlation isn't causation.

Comment: @000 you have an error in the terminal application provided by the operating system. This error is tickled by you running some application. We cannot debug your terminal program, though there might be some memory corruption from your program - but that requires a bit of a heroic effort to try to debug.

Comment: @000: then *why are you asking on Stack Overflow about your program*. **First** determine that the connection is not a coincidence, **then** ask a question here. Otherwise it is just a generic computer support issue and off-topic for that reason.

Comment: @000 _"as it works fine on another computer or in Xcode"_ That's way no proof you program is bug free.

Comment: I didn't run any other command between the two attempts at opening another terminal tab, other than `cd` and `ls`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just look at the program. Nothing there! And it's worked before in CLI too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not asking on SO **about my program**. I'm asking why it broke the terminal.

Comment: Also, by other computer I mean one running the same OS and using the same methods of running it.

Comment: @000 As for your programming problem: There could likely be an issue about the actually available stack sizes on a particular environment. You could easily hit the maximum available stack size because of the recursion. _"I'm not asking on SO **about my program**. I'm asking why it broke the terminal."_ Repeating this statement doesn't make it a better argument, it's useless to ask this way.

Comment: My car won't start, it worked fine yesterday!  Look, I made a photo of it.  Tell me what is wrong.

Comment: My car started a second ago, I just pressed the brakes once and now it stopped working! Look, I took a video of all the things that might have gone wrong, but it seems like nothing happened. Tell me what is wrong.

Comment: This is what I meant by "SO was more helpful than people not understanding simple English."

Answer (score 20):

You are claiming that there is a connection between your program running and your terminal breaking.

We now have two possibilities here:

- The program really is at fault. This now is a debugging issue, for which you did not provide enough context.
- The program is not at fault. This now is a general computing support issue, which is off topic.

Either way, your question would be off-topic.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: If the program wasn't at fault, why did it work just before I ran `cd ~`, `ls -Gal`, `make fibonacci`, and `./fibonacci` ?

Comment: And if the program was at fault, it's not a debugging issue as the program **works perfectly fine itself**. If you read the program, NOTHING could've resulted in this output.

Comment: @000: we don't know. We don't know what other processes run on your computer, or if there was a hardware problem with your memory that was triggered by temperature fluctuations, or that there was an automatic upgrade that broke your terminal, etc. Do you know?

Comment: So verify by trying it somewhere else?

Comment: I have. It works on another computer running same OS with same commands and on Xcode.

Comment: And also in xterm.

Comment: @000: if your program runs fine by itself, then the second option applies, and your question is still off topic. I know this can be upsetting, but *we cannot help here*, not without more information.

Comment: @000: and even with more information, *computer support questions are off-topic* here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you want the running applications at the time, the only other application running at the time was TextMate...

Comment: The program being at fault and the program not working are two different things. Maybe it was the `make`? Maybe it was the program itself? Either way, something happened in that timespace that broke it. I wasn't using TextMate in that timespace, I was using Terminal!

Comment: @000: you are going round in circles here. If your program broke the terminal, then it isn't working as designed. It may have produced output you expected, but it also produced output you did not expect, being your terminal broke. Your terminal not working is *an output of your program*. You are simultaneously stating your program is fine and your program is not fine here.

Comment: I'm stating that my program **worked** but it also caused **other problems**. Causing other problems does not imply it doesn't work, if it produces the expected output along with it. Also, it doesn't produce other problems on other computers, even when running the same OS & commands.

Comment: @000 Martijn is right. In your case I recommend this: On your own, try to isolate exactly what is triggering the issue from your program's output. Once you do that you will have a nice minimal test case. This will help you narrow down the cause. If you find that a certain, say, character combination output corrupts your terminal, you now have a specific cause and effect, and a concrete question about the terminal. You can now frame this as "outputting X corrupts *<whatever terminal I'm using>*" and now have a good question for unix.se. (PS `bash` is not a terminal, `gtkterm` is, for example)

Comment: Read and look at the program. Nothing's wrong, it's been run multiple times without any unintended consequences, even on the same OS & with the same commands. No syntax errors, no nothing.

Comment: @000 Well if nothing's wrong with your program, then it certainly isn't a programming question, is it? :) Signs point to the issue being caused by some per-machine configuration issue wrt whatever terminal you are using. You need to narrow it down on that machine (for example, have you tried other terminals?), then frame it as a terminal-related question on one of the computing help support sites. *This will help **you** get a handle on your problem!* It will also help you get an answer, as you will have a more concrete and well-defined question with less unknowns. Everybody wins! :)

Comment: In fact I have tried xterm as another terminal. Also, if I should've posted on the Unix/Linux or something SE sites, why didn't anyone help me get going on SO? Why just down vote a question instead of helping out? Bash is pretty much the only thing I can program most of the time, and without a 4.3 terminal it's infinitely difficult.

Comment: I should never have asked meta. Even SO was more helpful than people not understanding simple English.

Comment: @000: just because we disagree on the triage outcome of your problem doesn't mean you need to disparage us on our English comprehension. :-) I can see that you are upset about all this, but that doesn't mean your question is any more on topic. Sorry!